# List<int> to Chilkat.JsonArray

Tags: c#, chilkat

What's the best way to populate a Chilkat JsonArray with values from a List

```
List<int> MyList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Chilkat.JsonArray jsonArray = new Chilkat.JsonArray();
```

Can I do jsonArray.Load(???) or do I have to loop through the list with JsonArray.AddIntAt?

BTW I'm a C# newbie!

Comment: What is the problem in using `JsonArray.AddIntAt()`?

Comment: Probably should have said this is .NET Core

Comment: If looping through is the only way then no problem, I just thought there may be a better way 8-)

Answer (score 0):

I remember using Chilkat back in VB6. Are you tied to it?

If not then I would suggest maybe looking at using Newtonsoft.Json (available from NuGet).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547279/13436798) is an answer that I posted from earlier today...

Hope this helps

Comment: Only tied to it as I already know it. There's enough to learn with C# and .NET Core 8-)

Comment: To be honest, I would suggest using Newtonsoft.JSON instead as its pretty much the de facto JSON de/serialiser out there for .NET, although Microsoft have now made their own (System.Text.Json) which is pretty much the same. If you go to NuGet, it will likely be the top hit.  To start, check out here...https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm or for Microsofts ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to