# How to convert some RAW data from an API and save it into variables so i can work with them in C#

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm working on a personal project. Its a C# app that communicates with some web services using an API.

i finally got the first raw data with this few lines:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.abcd.com/token");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("username", usr);
            request.AddParameter("password", pass);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
```

and in postman the response (JSON) looks like :

> {"access_token":"aaaaaaa","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":899,"refresh_token":"bbbbbbb",".issued":"Fri,
>   01 May 2020 16:11:36 GMT",".expires":"Fri, 01 May 2020 16:26:36
>   GMT",".refreshexpires":"Fri, 01 May 2020 17:11:36 GMT"}

my next step is to find the way to separate those key/value pair into different variables in C# so i can work with them.

thank you so much for the help.

Comment: A quick stackoverlfow search would have found you a lot of answers to this question. You're attempting to convert a string array back into a C# Dictionary - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385421/most-elegant-way-to-convert-string-array-into-a-dictionary-of-strings for example.

Comment: i've searched an answer for 2 days.. but nothing worked... until something posted below.. but thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But I guess for small purpose no need to create a class rather use weakly typed data structure like this:

```
dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
//then use every property like this
responseObject.accessToken ...
responseObject.token_type.....
```

But you need to use Newtonsoft.Json for this too.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a JSON deserialiser to do this.

So you would create a class:

```
public class Response {
  public string accessToken {get; set;)
  public string token_type {get; set;)
  .....
}
```

And then use something like Newtonsoft.Json (available from NuGet) to deserialise:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

.....

var response = JsonConvert.Deserialise<Response>([RAW TEXT FROM REST CLIENT]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using Json.Net which will allow you to deserialize the JSON into an object like so. Note you'll need to download the package and then add `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
{
    "varone":"valueone"
}
```

```cs
public class MyJsonClass
{
    //JsonProperty isn't strictly required but I personally think it helps when trying to deserialize for sanity sake
    [JsonProperty("varone")]
    public string VarOneValue { get; set; } //The value will be "valueone" on deserialization
}
```

```cs
var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonObject>(JSONDATA);
Console.Write(myobj.VarOneValue); //Will be "valueone"
```

Nuget CLI: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Page: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json